# Get Parcelable from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parcelable

So I've been using firebase database to store some user data using Parcelables. Now, when I try to get those parcelables, I get this error saying that the class I'm using doesn't have a constructor with no arguments. Adding that constructor doesn't really solve anything. Is there some other way to get the parcelables from the database without actually parsing the information "by hand"?

Cheers everyone!

This is just a entry I insert into the database

```
AlarmParcel favorite = new AlarmParcel("id", "address", "name", "range", "units", latLng);
final ArrayList<AlarmParcel> favoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I retrieve that data

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        AlarmParcel alarm = postSnapshot.getValue(AlarmParcel.class);
        favoriteList.add(alarm);
    }

        mAdapter.setmAlarmData(favoriteList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

Aaand finally, the Alarm Parcelable (excluded getters and setters)

```
public class AlarmParcel implements Parcelable {
private String mId;
private String mAddress;
private String mName;
private String mRange;
private String mUnits;
private LatLng mPosition;

public AlarmParcel(String id, String address, String name, String range, String units, LatLng position)
{
    this.mId = id;
    this.mName = name;
    this.mAddress = address;
    this.mRange = range;
    this.mUnits = units;
    this.mPosition = position;
}

private AlarmParcel(Parcel in){
    mId = in.readString();
    mAddress = in.readString();
    mName = in.readString();
    mRange = in.readString();
    mUnits = in.readString();
    mPosition = in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public String toString() { return mId + "--" + mAddress + "--" + mName + "--" + mRange + "--" + mUnits + "--" + mPosition; }

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(mId);
    parcel.writeString(mAddress);
    parcel.writeString(mName);
    parcel.writeString(mRange);
    parcel.writeString(mUnits);
    parcel.writeParcelable(mPosition, PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<AlarmParcel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AlarmParcel>() {
    @Override
    public AlarmParcel createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new AlarmParcel(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public AlarmParcel[] newArray(int i) {
        return new AlarmParcel[i];
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was kind of tricky.

On top of adding a constructor with no arguments, the parcelable also needed setters...but these are CASE SENSITIVE. So, when you get the query from firebase, it may look for a *setname* method to build your parcelable instead of a *setName*, which is a more common name to have.

Hope this helps someone at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It need `a constructor with no arguments`

That means `empty constructor`,  So just add it so that she will satisfied

```
public AlarmParcel(){}
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried that and even though the error disappears the parcelable object isn't created properly at all.

Comment: hmm..  maybe change this code `
    parcel.writeParcelable(mPosition, i);` ?